# How to Split the comma separated cell by condition google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

**My Sheet look like this:**

**-ID   Values**

```
1.  Name,Email,Company
2.  Email,Name,Company
3.  Company,Email,Name
```

-I would like to convert the data to name,email,company by condition of ID

**Example Output:**

```
1.  Name    Email   Company
2.  Name    Email   Company
3.  Name    Email   Company
```

I need some assistance on this topic!! How I can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "by condition of ID"?  I guessing your familiar with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2:.

```
    =arrayformula(SPLIT(B2:B5,","))
```

If B2:B5 has comma separated values,C2 will give you the answer

Comment: But I would like to split by the ID value. ID value need to be in condition to split name,email and company

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID Values to Example output like this assuming the ID Values are in A2:A4:

```
=split(A2,",")
```

=split(join(",",index(split(A3,","),1,2),index(split(A3,","),1,1),index(split(A3,","),1,3)),",")

=split(join(",",index(split(A4,","),1,3),index(split(A4,","),1,2),index(split(A4,","),1,1)),",")

Comment: How to add if condition for the above formula.. Like If(B2=2, split(join(",",index(split(A3,","),1,2),index(split(A3,","),1,1),index(split(A3,","),1,3)),","))

Comment: This working for me but i would like to use some multiple if condition like below. Is there any possible way.. If(B3=2, split(join(",",index(split(A3,","),1,2),index(split(A3,","),‌​1,1),index(split(A3,‌​","),1,3)),","))

Comment: @SarathVenkat Yes,an if can be done if a Company can be identified as different from a Name. An Email can be identified. Without seeing real data, I can't tell.

Comment: @SarathVenkat See this spreadsheet. It creates a Form ID based on where the email address is and the number of columns created by the split. I left out the 1s for simplicity, but you know how to add those. I also solved the single email problem. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LLiJlJZ4OM6YcUdZX0ic_InU5iKG8YmBsKw8IjhwyTE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try split and sort:

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,","))))`

[image]

- used double `TRANSPOSE` because sort works for vertical arrays only.

Comment: Thanks, but  my data contains different name, email and company so sorting of data is complicated.

Comment: Please share some dummy data that looks like real data.